# The constant time value for an electronic device

Tags: electrical, time, device

i am working in a data science project that require certain information about electronic devices. So I know that for each electrical circuit there is a permanent regime and a transient regime and while passing from the transient regime to the permanent regime there is a certain characteristic value of time T which is constant for each circuit. what i need to know is for domestic electronic devices is there an average or maximum value of T (the device is unknown) after which we are sure that the transient regime is probably over.
i will appretiate any information that can help me .

Comment: This varies highly from device to device and from one part of the device to another part of the same device. For each device there will be slowly changing parts and quick varying parts. Why do you need to know this ? Can you add more details to what you plan to do with this information ?

Comment: There is an average. Of course there's always an average but nobody will be able to tell you what it is because it's unimportant. Similarly, for stars in space there is an average distance for all stars to earth but who cares what that is. The maximum value is equally unknown because there may be one specific device (or star) somewhere that far exceeds the sum of the others but, like I said earlier, who cares?

Comment: I'm not sure how this question would work for an unknown household device. My light bulb has a transient warm-up period which is on the order of less than a second, while my oven takes minutes to reach its steady-state temperature and mode of operation where it cycles around the operating point. It may be prudent to revise or clarify your problem statement, or to narrow it to a smaller class of devices.

Comment: In fact I want to use the electronic signature of the device to recognize which device is used by a machine learning classification model. First in order to detect the signature I pick the recorded consumption between two event detection but i find out that the record is quite too long because the transient state end up quickly and 80% of the record is in the steady-state which affect the quality of the classification so wanted to optimize the record in a that I only detect the transient state.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheets may tell you these times.

Temperature will affect the "time".

The amount of wiring, which stores Electric Charge just like clouds store charge before lightning occurs, will affect the "time".

The use of proper or improper voltages, needed to allow successful internal operation, will affect the "time".

And variations during production, as the silk_screen style of manufacturing has variations in alignment as various layers are placed, as thicknesses of the layers vary, etc etc all affect the speed of the internal transistors and thus affect the "time".

Go examine the "datasheet 74LS04" and then the "datasheet 74LS00" and then the "datasheet 74LS74" and then the "datasheet 74LS181" and then the "datasheet 74LS244", as important devices with "times" that vary dependent on the complexity of internal transistors and logical operations.

=================================

For the 5 devices I've mentioned, the "times" will be 5 nanoSeconds to 80 nanoSeconds, depending on the Power Voltage, the Wiring, the Temperature, and the complexity (the 74LS181 is the most complex).

A nanosecond is about how much "time" required by light (photons) to travel 1 foot (or 30 centimeters).

These 5 devices are 1mm to 2mm in size, and the internal transistors need "time" for their own changing. You can examine the 74LS181, perhaps the complete path from Cin to Cout, and count the logic gates which each contribute delays.

By the way, the 5 devices I've named are nearly all you need to make a computer. You will need to provide a substantial memory (static RAM has its own "time" requirements.)

Comment: By "devices", I don't think he means electronic components like logic IC's.  I think he means devices like phones.

Comment: In fact I want to use the electronic signature of the device to recognize which device is used by a machine learning classification model. First in order to detect the signature I pick the recorded consumption between two event detection but i find out that the record is quite too long because the transient state end up quickly and 80% of the record is in the steady-state which affect the quality of the classification so wanted to optimize the record in a that I only detect the transient state.